# mapviewoffile problem can't use it more than once?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

```
    auto Readstring = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFileW, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 4096);

printf("message has been sent to kernel [Read]! \n");


FlushViewOfFile(Readstring, 4096);
UnmapViewOfFile(Readstring);


// maybe am stupid

auto send_test = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFileW, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 4096);


printf("message has been sent to kernel [Test]! \n");


FlushViewOfFile(send_test, 4096);
UnmapViewOfFile(send_test);
```

that's what am trying to do and everytime i try to send the "Read" string + "Test" string it doesn't do anything but , if i only send "Read" string to my mapped section i can read it fine . i just want to know is it a problem because am not defining any offset to mapviewoffile but i have also tried to use (sizeof(char*)) and it didn't work. basically its simple i just want to send this 2 strings to my second process which has a while loop running it will check the first string and if its equal to the shared memory section it will execute the other while loop which keeps reading shared memory until its equal to the string "Test" this is how am reading the strings from my second process "its kernel btw".

```
while (TRUE)
{
    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "running waiting for a command to execute.. \n");
    ReadSharedMemory();
    if (strcmp((PCHAR)SharedSection, "Stop") == 0) {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "breaking out of the loop");
        break;
    }
    while (!(PCHAR)SharedSection == NULL && strcmp((PCHAR)SharedSection, "Read") == 0)
    {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Read loop is running\n");



        ReadSharedMemory();
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "sharedsection string - > : %s\n", (PCHAR)SharedSection);



        LARGE_INTEGER Timeout;
        Timeout.QuadPart = RELATIVE(SECONDS(1));
        KeDelayExecutionThread(KernelMode, FALSE, &Timeout);


        if (!(PCHAR)SharedSection == NULL && strcmp((PCHAR)SharedSection, "Test") == 0)
        {
            DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "it works finally !!!! \n");
            DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "[Test while loop]sharedsection string - > : %s\n", (PCHAR)SharedSection);

        }
    }
```

and here is how i am reading shared memory

```
if (sectionHandle)
    return;

if (SharedSection)
    ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), SharedSection);

SIZE_T ulViewSize = 1024 * 10;
NTSTATUS ntStatus = ZwMapViewOfSection(sectionHandle, NtCurrentProcess(), &SharedSection, 0, ulViewSize, NULL, &ulViewSize, ViewShare, 0, PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_NOCACHE);
if (ntStatus != STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    DbgPrintEx(0,0,"ZwMapViewOfSection fail! Status: %p\n", ntStatus);
    ZwClose(sectionHandle);
    return;
}
DbgPrintEx(0,0,"ZwMapViewOfSection completed!\n");
DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "String is : %s now !\n", (PCHAR)SharedSection);
```

and sharedsections is just a null PVOID.

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve]? It's a bit hard to try and understand what you are asking purely from your explanation + code *snippet*. A fully formed example would help.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  edited my post : couldn't add much better because i haven't seen anyone having this problem so i can't create an example because i really don't know why its doing that .

Comment: I think tou may not understand what a [mcve] is about. Perhaps read about [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). The basic point is that you should produce a simple program (that we can cut-n-paste) that reproduces the problem and does not include anything unrelated to the problem. This means a `main` function + whatever else you need to cause the problem, but nothing else. Constructing this often reveals the cause of the problem btw.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  ok i will try to create it , maybe i will get it to be fixed :D

Comment: @Jesper Juhl i have explained my problem right now much better .